# How to get list of checkboxes not checked on page model razor page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I working on razor page with .NET core 7 . I face issue I can't  pass  checkboxes that not checked with values as 1 2 3  from html page to page model on post method ?

so user click submit button then on post method fire then it will collect check boxes values not checked  as list

view model used

```
public class UserAccessViewModel
        {

            public UserAccess userAccess { get; set; }
            public int[] checks { get; set; }
        }
```

on page.cshtml

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <form method="post">
        <button id="FillCheckBox" type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      
    <input id="StockTake" name="UserAccessViewModel.checks" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="1">
        <label for="lblStockTake">Stock Take</label>
    <input id="ShelfLabelPrint" name="UserAccessViewModel.checks" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="2">
        <label for="lblShelfLabel">Shelf Label Print</label>

    <input id="Transfer" name="UserAccessViewModel.checks" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="3">
        <label for="lblTransfer" style="margin-right:5px;">Transfer</label>

        
                    
        
    </form>
```

on pagemodel .cshtml.cs

```
public async Task OnPost(UserAccessViewModel UserAccessViewModel)
{
   //How to pass checkboxes not checked to razor page
}
```

for more details what I need

[image: pass unchecked checkboxes to razor page]

Comment: this answer not suitable to my suitation

Comment: can any one help me the solution provided not suitable to my case so can any one help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try modify your viewmodel:

```
public class UserAccessViewModel
    {
        //other properties...
        public List<CheckBoxModel> Checks { get; set; } = default!;
    }

    public class CheckBoxModel
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; } = default!;
    }
```

Page Model(I tried with Privacy Page of a default RazorPage project):

```
public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
    {
        //.......

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet =true)]
        public UserAccessViewModel userAccessViewModel { get; set; }

        

        public void OnGet()
        {
            userAccessViewModel=new UserAccessViewModel() 
            { 
                Checks=new List<CheckBoxModel> 
                { 
                    new CheckBoxModel(){Value=1,Label="Stock Take"} ,
                    new CheckBoxModel(){Value=2,Label="Shelf Label Print"} ,
                    new CheckBoxModel(){Value=3,Label="Transfer"} ,
                } 
            };
        }
        public void OnPost(UserAccessViewModel UserAccessViewModel)
        {

        }
    }
```

Codes in Page(add hidden input hold your int values and bind the statue of selected or not with `asp-for` in checkbox):

```
@page
@model PrivacyModel


<form method="post">
    <button id="FillCheckBox" type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.userAccessViewModel.Checks.Count; i++)
    {
        <input asp-for="userAccessViewModel.Checks[i].Selected" type="checkbox"/>
        <input asp-for="userAccessViewModel.Checks[i].Value" hidden />
        <label asp-for="userAccessViewModel.Checks[i].Label">@Model.userAccessViewModel.Checks[i].Label</label>
        <input asp-for="userAccessViewModel.Checks[i].Label" hidden />
    }    
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

not selected checkbox:

```
var notchecked = userAccessViewModel.Checks.Where(x => x.Selected == false).ToList();
```