# Create a checkbox using Enum in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a checkbox using enum. I can create a simple checklist using enum without any issues, but it give me error for when I use `asp-for=""` in my checklist.

Whenever I use `asp-for=""`, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unexpected 'asp-for' expression result type 'Website.Data.Enum.CollectionCategory' for . 'asp-for' must be of type 'System.Boolean' or 'System.String' that can be parsed as a 'System.Boolean' if 'type' is 'checkbox'.

I have created radio buttons using enum *with* `asp-for=""` and it worked without any problem.

I searched online why that is the case and here is what I found:

> Unfortunately, to *Render Checkbox for each enum value* is not possible – by definition you always only select one value of an enumeration. If you want checkboxes, you can make separate Boolean attributes for each checkbox.

I have searched for multiple solutions but unfortunately, my problem is still unresolved.

Here is my code:

Enum definition:

```cs
public enum CollectionCategory
{
    [Display(Name = "Veg")]
    Veg = 0,

    [Display(Name = "NonVeg")]
    NonVeg = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Breakfast")]
    Breakfast = 2,

    [Display(Name = "Lunch")]
    Lunch = 3,

    [Display(Name = "Dinner")]
    Dinner = 4
}
```

Model class:

```cs
public class Post
{
    // Code Before

    public CollectionCategory CollectionCategory { get; set; }

    // Code After
}
```

View model:

```cs
public class CreatePostViewModel
{
    // Code Before
    public CollectionCategory CollectionCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreatePostViewModel postVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var post = new Post
        {
            // Code before
            CollectionCategory = postVM.CollectionCategory,                    
        };

        _postInterface.Add(post);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
    }

    return View(postVM);
}
```

View (*works fine without `asp-for=""`*):

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
    @foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CollectionCategory)))
    {
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="CollectionCategory" class="btn-check" id="@value" value="@((int)value)" required>
        <label asp-for="CollectionCategory" class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="@value">@value</label>
    }
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what about using [`select` box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740638/using-enum-for-dropdown-list-in-asp-net-mvc-core) then add [`multiple` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51979620) to it?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,juding from your codes in your controller,you just want a single CollectionCategory in your viewmodel,radio buttons is more suitable for your sceanaior

If you want bind value to multipule CollectionCategory,you have to create a model that has a property type of `bool` for checkbox , and create a hiden input to hold the value of the enum;

a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244185/how-to-get-list-of-checkboxes-not-checked-on-page-model-razor-page/76250700#76250700) I once answered here.

Here's a minimal example for you,hopes help:

Models:

```
public enum CollectionCategory
{
    [Display(Name = "Veg")]
    Veg = 0,

    [Display(Name = "NonVeg")]
    NonVeg = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Breakfast")]
    Breakfast = 2,

    [Display(Name = "Lunch")]
    Lunch = 3,

    [Display(Name = "Dinner")]
    Dinner = 4
}


public class CheckboxModel
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public CollectionCategory CollectionCategory { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }
}


public class CreatePostViewModel
{
    public List<CheckboxModel> Checks { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Check()
{
    var viewmodel = new CreatePostViewModel();
    foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(CollectionCategory)))
    {
        var checkboxmodel = new CheckboxModel()
        {
            CollectionCategory = ( CollectionCategory)Enum.Parse(typeof(CollectionCategory), name,true),
            IsChecked = false,
            Label = name,

        };
        viewmodel.Checks.Add(checkboxmodel);
    }

    return View(viewmodel);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Check(CreatePostViewModel viewmodel)
{
    //...........
    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

View:

```
@model CreatePostViewModel

<form method="post">

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Checks.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Checks[i].IsChecked"   >
            <label asp-for="@Model.Checks[i].Label">@Model.Checks[i].Label </label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Checks[i].CollectionCategory" hidden />
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Checks[i].Label" hidden />
        </div>
     }
    
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Result:
[image]